# VBA Code for uniform Ranking in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this vba code for ranking

```
Sub RankArray()
    With Range("Distribution").Offset(0, 1)
        .FormulaArray = "=RANK(Distribution,Distribution)"
    End With
End Sub
```

but it is giving me a result like :

```
 1 2 3 4 4 6 7 7 7 10 11 12 12 14
```

Not in sequence because some rank are getting repeat

I want the only VBA code not excel formula for ranking that will give me result like below:

```
1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 8 9 10 10 11 12
```

Comment: It's giving you the correct answer. Because you have 2 x 4th places, by definition there is no 5th. Similarly, you have 3 x 7th places, so there is no 8th or 9th place. This is down to mathematical principles, and not Excel

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, and it's by no means very clear, you want to know how to use the `Rank` function in VBA, rather than inserting the function into the document for the result? If that's the case, take a look at WorksheetFunction.Rank Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840358.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a different formula for that kind of ranking. Something like:

```
Sub RankArray()
    With Range("Distribution").Offset(0, 1)
        .Resize(1).FormulaArray = "=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&RANK(R[0]C[-1],Distribution))),RANK(Distribution,Distribution),0)))"
        .FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```